# Reac-Bootstrap how to overwrite form-input background

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, next.js, react-bootstrap

I've got a `next.js` application and am using `react-bootstrap`. I am trying to overwrite my default form background from that blueish gray (`#e8f0fe or rgb(232, 240, 254)`) that bootstrap is using for inputs to white.

I am currently customizing the bootstrap variables via a `custom.bootstrap.scss` file

```
$theme-colors: (
   'primary': #e28215,
   'secondary': #83b8f3,
   'tertiary': #1575e2,
   'headings': #2b363f,
   'body': #5b6b79,
   'inputBorderNormal': #c3ced6,
   'inputBorderFocus': #90a3b0,
   'darkBG': #2b363f,
   'lightBG': #eef0f3,
   'input-bg': #fff,
   'input-bg-disabled': #fff,
);

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

this file is then imported into my `index.scss`:

```
@import './custom.bootstrap.scss'
```

I am then using the `index.scss` in my `_app.js` like this:

```
import '../style/index.scss';
```

The theming seems to work as my primary button is orange, but I can't get the form background to change (I can't even overwrite it on element level with `!important`)

Please find a repo [here](https://github.com/FBosler/next-bootstrap-theming-development)

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a code sandbox to demonstrate this
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-feather-ppg8q?file=/style/custom.bootstrap.scss

There were two changes:

1.instead of importing `index.scss` import the custom bootstrap file into `_app.js`

`import "../style/custom.bootstrap.scss";`

2. Declare the variables directly into the file and apply them.

```
$darkBG: #2b363f;
$primary:#e28215;
$tertiary:  #1575e2;

// ... Rest of your colors..

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

body {
    padding: 20px 20px 60px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: $primary;
  }

form {
    background-color:$darkBG;
}
.my-3 {
 background-color:$tertiary;
}
```